# How can I convert ellipse to path in Microsoft Blend 2022?

Tags: expression-blend

I have a problem with converting an ellipse to a path in Microsoft Blend 2022. My first try was WPF App template and .NET 6.0 Framework, but options in Format > Path are disabled.

[image]

After some research I found this ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/draw-shapes-and-paths?view=vs-2022)):

> Convert to Path is not currently available for UWP apps that have a
> minimum TargetPlatformVersion of 10.0.16299.0 or later.

So I tried to use "old" "WPF App (.NET Framework)" template with 4.8 framework, but path related options are not available. I tried to switch Target Framework to 4.7.2 and 4.6.1, but it still doesnt work.

**Do I have to install older .NET Framework, or Visual Studio / Microsoft Blend to do this?** If so - which version should allow me to convert basic shapes (like ellipse, rectangle etc.) to motion path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "went back in time" to **Visual Studio / Blend 2017**.

**It works with .NET Framework 4.8.**

Project created from scratch in Blend 2017, copied MainWindow.xaml file:

[image]

Maybe someone tried this in 2019 version?